# SNAPSHOT updates for local Maven repository

Tags: java, maven, nexus

It is a usual policy to remove SNAPSHOT versions in Nexus when a release version is available. Does the local Maven repository also delete SNAPSHOT versions when -- after asking Nexus for the newest SNAPSHOT -- it finds out that no SNAPSHOT version is available?

Answer (score 0):

No. The SNAPSHOT ought to stay in the repo. So you should consider releasing a final version (without the SNAPSHOT modifier) then.

Comment: I am sorry, but do you mean local repository or Nexus when you say "repo"?